# Fastavro Schemaless Reader

Tags: python, avro, fastavro

My Follow-up question of this -> [[Avro deserialization from Kafka using fastavro]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473880/avro-deserialization-from-kafka-using-fastavro)

Is there any way to read all records from avro file(Without Header) using fastavro schemaless_reader() ?

[image: Schemaless_Reader]

Comment: Please do not post code (or other textual content) as an image. Usually you should copy the text and include it in the post, formatted as code. In this particular case you have posted a screenshot from the documentation, which you could have just linked to: [schemaless_reader](https://fastavro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reader.html#fastavro._read_py.schemaless_reader)

Answer (score 0):

The `schemaless_reader` can only read a single record so that probably won't work.

If you have a true avro file, even if you strip out the header, there might still be other non-record information (for example, the sync marker) so I wouldn't suggest taking an actual avro file, stripping the header, and expect to still be able to read it.